# Where should we discuss about features?

Tags: discussion

SE aim is to have questions that have a "correct" answers. We still need a place for questions to discuss about a new feature, a GSoC project... Where should we do that? use a mailing list? the forum? irc? slack/mattermost...?

X+

Answer (score 3):

I'd put in a soft-vote for the forum over SE. The forum is built for discussions. And it does still exist :)

Comment: it exists, it's not dead, but smells a bit funny. As in, asking the students to move to the forum if no one of the community is there might not be the warmest welcome we could offer ;)